# How to remove elements from Array in Perl less than a number in best possible way

Tags: arrays, perl

Input Array : @Array = (1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,100)

Threashold : 5

Output Array : @Array = (5,6,7,8,9,9,100)

Comment: Please show what you have written and explain in detail what problems you have with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *best way*, because that depends on what you like. Do you want it to be short? Easy to read? Easy to understand for the new guy?

There is more than one way in Perl though.

The most concise one is probably to use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
@Array = grep { $_ < 5 } @Array;
```

If you think that's too weird and the maintenance guy will not understand it, write your own loop.

Comment: [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) :)

Answer (score -4):

$cutOut = 5;

@Array = grep {$_ <= $cutOut} @Array ;

Comment: It's good that you are trying to answer your own question, but at least actually answer the question you asked. You had `5` in the question, and you said _less than_. Now you're showing `9` and lesser-equal. That's not the right answer. Also, please [edit] and use code-formatting and add an explanation of why this answers the question and how it works. Code-only answers are frowned upon.